# How can I align an image and a horizontal menu in the same line?

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

net and I've been trying to figure out for hours how to align an image and a horizontal menu in the same line, but Ive had no luck. This is my code so far... http://i66.tinypic.com/2ilcuft.png
 Thank You!.

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" class="auto-style7">
    <div class="auto-style2">
         <img src="Images/ridgeway-logo.jpg" class="auto-style1" /><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" BackColor="#99CCFF" CssClass="auto-style4" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calisto MT" Font-Overline="False" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="Black" Text="Log In" />
         <br />
         <div class="auto-style3">
             <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Names="Nirmala UI" Font-Size="Larger" Font-Strikeout="False" ForeColor="Black" Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#B3D9FF" Font-Bold="True" Font-Overline="False" Font-Underline="True" />
                 <Items>
                     <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/homeBlue (1).png" NavigateUrl="~/Home.aspx" Text="HOME" Value="Home"></asp:MenuItem>
                     <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/AboutUs.aspx" Text="ABOUT US" Value="About Us">
                         <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/SingleFamily.aspx" Text="Single-Family" Value="Single-Family"></asp:MenuItem>
                         <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MultiFamily.aspx" Text="Multi-Family" Value="Multi-Family"></asp:MenuItem>
                         <asp:MenuItem Text="Ridgeway Projects" Value="Ridgeway Projects"></asp:MenuItem>
                         <asp:MenuItem Text="Work In Progress" Value="Work In Progress"></asp:MenuItem>
                     </asp:MenuItem>
                     <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/TheBestSub.aspx" Text="THE BEST SUB" Value="The Best Sub"></asp:MenuItem>
                     <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Careers.aspx" Text="CAREERS" Value="Careers"></asp:MenuItem>
                     <asp:MenuItem Text="MORE" Value="MORE">
                         <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Training.aspx" Text="TRAINING" Value="Training">
                             <asp:MenuItem Text="Courses" Value="Courses"></asp:MenuItem>
                         </asp:MenuItem>
                         <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/OurCustomers.aspx" Text="OUR CUSTOMERS" Value="Our Customers"></asp:MenuItem>
                         <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Directory.aspx" Text="DIRECTORY" Value="Directory">
                             <asp:MenuItem Text="New Item" Value="New Item"></asp:MenuItem>
                         </asp:MenuItem>
                         <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Service.aspx" Text="WARRANTY SERVICE" Value="Warranty Service"></asp:MenuItem>
                     </asp:MenuItem>
                 </Items>
                 <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#DDEEFF" Font-Bold="True" Font-Underline="True" />
                 <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#66CCFF" />
             </asp:Menu>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not include code as an image. Please post as text then format as code. We may need to copy your code to provide an answer.

Comment: You're absolutely right! Ill repost

Comment: It's still pretty hard to tell but generally you'll need to add css `display: inline-block` to everything you want in the row - divs, menus, etc, everything that normally displays as a block.

Comment: Thanks it worked!